# SWT text output and new lines

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, newline

I have a program that I'm using as an experiment to get used to GUI. It basically takes a quadratic in f(x)=ax^2+bx+c form and finds the real zeros, y-intercept, and axis of symmetry.. It works well as far as the calculations and all. My issue is that I created a non editable text box (using window builder **SWT** app) and no matter what I do, it always prints everything on one single line! \n doesnt work, \r\n doesnt work... Please help.

```
Button btnNewButton = new Button(shlParacalc, SWT.NONE);
btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        String aval = alphabox.getText();
        double a = Double.parseDouble(aval);

        String bval = betabox.getText();
        double b = Double.parseDouble(bval);

        String cval = gammabox.getText();
        double c = Double.parseDouble(cval);


        CalcLib mathObj = new CalcLib();    

        double yint = mathObj.yIntercept(a, b, c);
        double axis = mathObj.Axis(a, b);
        double zero[] = mathObj.Zero(a, b, c);


        outputbox.append("y-intercept = " + yint); // these four lines need
        outputbox.append("axis of symmetry = " + axis); //to be printed
        outputbox.append("1st zero = " + zero[0]); //on individual lines
        outputbox.append("2nd zero = " + zero[1]);
```

Comment: what's the type of outputbox ?

Comment: It's of type Text not TextArea or Text Field.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Createamultiplelinetextfield.htm

Comment: What style bits are specified on the `Text` constructor?

Comment: Hmm Im going to try to make it multi-lined and perhaps the \r\n will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong [style bits](http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits). This code works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Add text");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {

            text.append("y-intercept = \n");
            text.append("axis of symmetry = \n");
            text.append("1st zero = \n");
            text.append("2nd zero = \n");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. All I had to do was replace the SWT.NONE with SWT.MULTI...Thanks